# Decision making in different intervals in MDPs

Tags: markov-process, reinforcement-learning

I want to model a problem as an MDP model where every day is divided into small time slots (for example minutes) and two decisions `A` and `B` should be optimized. At the beginning of every day, both decisions are made. However, the decision `B` for other time slots on the same day are constant and should not be changed. That is, if decision `B` is made at 7 A.M., the same decision is repeated over 7:01, 7:02, ...., However, it is possible to change decision `A` without any problem.

I willing to know if this problem can be modeled as an MDP and in case of possibility, how it is possible? If there is any paper which has addressed the same assumption, I would be thankful to know.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it comes up in hierarchical RL/options all the time. The keyword you are looking for is Semi-MDPs.

Comment: or [the Options framework](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0004370299000521)

Comment: Thank you. But I do not understand why SMDP? Is it possible to model this problem as a conventional MDP problem? I think hierarchical is superior to the conventional MDP in terms of convergence speed. Is it right?

Comment: SMDPs allow you to consider actions at different time scales. They do not need to be hierarchical